# Installing new and old versions of Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

So I saw this post: [http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/download-and-install-older-versions-of-xcode-xcode-previous-releases.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128192100/http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/download-and-install-older-versions-of-xcode-xcode-previous-releases.html)

(new location: [at iosdevelopertips.com](http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/download-and-install-older-versions-of-xcode-xcode-previous-releases.html))

about downloading older versions of Xcode.  Up to now, I have always just downloaded the newest version of Xcode from the App Store and let it do its thing.  Recently on one computer that has Xcode 4.5 installed on it, I noticed that if I create a new project, I only get the iOS 6.0 simulators, not the 5.0 or 5.1.

1. My first question is, do I need older versions of Xcode to build apps for older OS (e.g. iOS 4, iOS 5.0, 5.1, etc)?
2. If so, what's the best way of installing these older versions of Xcode.  I see that they have the command line tools to download as well.  I'm not sure how all that stuff works.
3. What's the best way to update to the latest Xcode but keeping the old Xcode around?  On a different machine that had Xcode 4.4.1 installed, I thought I could download Xcode 4.5 from the ADC website and install it.  I downloaded it, double-clicked on the .dmg, then double-clicked on the Xcode file.  This then installed Xcode 4.5 without asking me where I wanted it installed so I could keep the older version of Xcode (assuming that I need it as stated in my 1st question).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I noticed that if I create a new project, I only get the iOS 6.0 simulators, not the 5.0 or 5.1.

Choose your project target and in `Summary` tab, set the lowest **Deployment Target** for your app (I think the default value is 6.0 in Xcode 4.5).

> My first question is, do I need older versions of Xcode to build apps for older OS (e.g. iOS 4, iOS 5.0, 5.1, etc)?

If you've updated from old version of Xcode, you can use the old SDK & simulator in new version.

> If so, what's the best way of installing these older versions of Xcode. I see that they have the command line tools to download as well. I'm not sure how all that stuff works.

Actually, different versions of Xcode can stay happily with each other. It is a App Bundle right now.

> third question

Just drag the new version of Xcode to Application folder. That's done. :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1) Yes. I renname Xcode to add the version number (i.e. Xcode_441.app)

2) I keep an archive of all versions of Xcode that I have downloaded so they are available after Apple pulls them from their download site.

3) Renaming them works for me, and I usually grab the direct download, when available, instead of getting it from the MAS. Try renaming Xcode before doing an install.

You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to have multiple XCode installations by customizing the install path.  Also note that the new 4.x install model is app bundles under Applications which are self contained so it's possible to just rename the old before installing the new XCode.  You can also download the newest (4.5) from the developer site.

You can also add the old simulators by going to XCode preferences in 4.5.

Look under XCode, preferences, downloads.  XCode 4.5 offers the 5.0 and 5.1 simulators for download.  The same place that you download the command line tools.

For example, I added the 5.0 Simulator to my XCode 4.5 installation to go along with the 6.0 Simulator:

[image: XCode Downloads]