# iPad 2 and iPad 3 website testing

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

Is there a way in the Apple iOS Simulator to test a website on an iPad 2 and an iPad 3? I have the latest version of xcode and iOS Simulator. I believe the resolution difference on the devices are causing some issues for a site, which I'd like to debug.

If the iOS Simulator does not offer an option, is there any other way of testing on these devices without actually owning both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't switch between iPad2 & iPad3 with the simulator.  Your options with the simulator is to:

- change between non-retina and retina resolutions and
- iOS versions.

If you're debugging resolution issues, note on the Hardware menu, you can select between iPad and iPad retina.

[image]

You can also go to XCode preferences, Download and download older iOS simulators.

[image]

Outside of that, your options are to get your hands on actual devices which is the ultimate way to test what will really happen :)

Comment: Wonderful. I was looking for how to download older iOS Simulators. Thank you!

Comment: Note that you can also have multiple versions of Xcode side by side if you have issues or want even older simulators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575310/installing-new-and-old-versions-of-xcode/12575390#12575390

Answer (score 0):

I think This One Can Help You ,
Try [This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ijoeapleklopieoejahbpdnhkjjgddem)

Answer (score 0):

No, the iOS simulator doesn't really work that way.

You can choose the iOS version (iOS6 only now, depending if you have the newest version of XCode), but not the device version (2 vs 3).

Comment: Xcode 4.5's simulator also supports iOS 5.0 and 5.1; they're available as optional components in Xcode->Preferences, Downloads.